# Merge <int, string> and <int, double> into <double,string> C# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, merge

If my dictionary 1 is :

```
0 : string1
1 : string2
2 : string3
```

And my dictionary 2 is :

```
0 : 28.0
1 : 12.6
2 : -12.4
```

How do I get a combined dictionary with :

```
28.0  : string1
12.6  : string2
-12.4 : string3
```

This is how I have used them so far

```
SortedDictionary<int, double> map2 = new SortedDictionary<int, double>();
SortedDictionary<int, string> map1 = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
```

Edit - For this question, assume the keys in both the dictionaries are sequential and in increasing order and always the same.

Comment: What happens if one of the dictionaries contains a value that the other one doesn't?

Comment: @maccettura Answer in answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming both dictionaries have the same count and have the same keys:

```
map1.ToDictionary(x => map2[x.Key], x => x.Value)
```

This would fail if the second dictionary has duplicated values.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I was trying something close by but it was wrong! Thanks!

Comment: @maccettura. Dictionaries have an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) which accepts an argument of the same type as the dictionary key. It looks like an index but is effectively the key. And yes, the examples show this key.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I know that.  What I was saying is that if the OP's example had the index (meaning the actual order index) you would certainly not be able to access it by an arbitrary key.  But since I misread and the dictionarys have a `int` key Selman's answer is correct.  I have upvoted